# Variance in set of different random variables

Tags: variance, random-variable, dispersion

Imagine we have sample of values a_1, a_2,...a_n, with a_i value originating from a normal distribution with mean mu_i_a and variance var_i_a, thus each value is single realization of different random variable. Then we have another sample of values b_1,..b_n, with value b_i originating from a normal distribution with mean mu_i_b and variance var_i_b. How can we compare dispersion of first sample (that is, values a_i,...a_n) with dispersion of the other sample (that is, values b_1, ... b_n).

A practical example, which can be related to this situation, imagine that we have average yearly salary for each state in USA in 1990 (mean +/- SEM for each state) and the same in 2010. The question is, how to measure if the state-specific mean salaries became more or less dispersed across time. For example, some politicians take measure to decrease salary inhomogenity across USA states, how to quantify if their measures have been succesfull?

This is edited version of previous question, so to make the question more clear.

Comment: Isn't the sample variance for each set of values what you want ?

Comment: Imagine we measure average height of a person in each state of USA and for east state of EU. We would like to know if heights in USA are more or less dispersed than in EU. Notable, height in each individual state represents specific random variable. Or we compare dispersion aross USA states between 2 different years (such as 1900 and 2000).

Comment: Is the question: How to measure dispersion of a random sample of independent, but not identically distributed variables?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: If they are plausibly normally distributed, an F test might be what you want.

Comment: Do you have only aggregates per state (like one mean and one variance)? Or many individual observations per state?

Comment: Just mean and standard error.

Comment: I'd propose you to add a new section to your question with the research question, the structure of the available data, and how it was collected. There is most certainly a (not so complicated) standard statistical approach for this kind of problem. The current wording is very confusing.

Comment: I have added a concrete example.

Comment: I find the question strange because there are no relationships hypothesized among any of the data: your suppositions are no stronger than stating you have two batches of numbers.  Choose whatever measure of dispersion you like for comparing them.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, so in the hypothesized example with the salaries, for example if there would be salary disparities in sense that  in some of the states people earn more than in the others and measures are taken to reduces such disparities, it is not possible to quantify the effect in statistically sound way?

Comment: Sure, as I stated: use any reasonable measure of dispersion.  I suspect your model is not appropriate, because it's not useful (it employs twice as many parameters as you have data, meaning you can't learn anything about any of those parameters) and (as others have noted) that makes your question confusing.

Comment: Is there any better model? The situation as described in the example must pop-up in the practice often. But I do not know how to approach it.

Comment: If your real interest is in salaries and their distributions, you seem to ask for comparing diversity. Diversity measures have their own tag here, which you can peruse [tag:diversity]

Comment: Models don't just "pop up:" they are conceived of by people to help understand and reason from the data.  *Nobody* uses a model like this because it's useless for understanding any dataset!

Comment: Popping-out referred to the structure of problem with the dispersion of salaries, I think this kind of problem might be not uncommon in real world. One I idea I got would be to calculate average absolute deviation for each year and use knowledge of standard errors to calculate confidence interval, this would allow us to evaluate change in dispersion across years.

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> We would like to know if heights in USA are more or less dispersed than in EU

I take this to mean that you want to compare the variance of two samples. This can be done with an F test which tests whether the *ratio* of the variances of the two sample is equal to 1. For example, in R, we can create two samples, with different means, but the same variance:

```
N <- 100
set.seed(15)
sample1 <- rnorm(N, 1, 1)
sample2 <- rnorm(N, 2, 1)

var.test(sample1, sample2)
```

produces:

```
F test to compare two variances

data:  sample1 and sample2
F = 0.81734, num df = 99, denom df = 99, p-value = 0.3173
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5499379 1.2147528
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.8173363
```

so there is insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis that the variances are equal. Now we do the same simulation with different variances:

```
N <- 100
set.seed(15)
sample1 <- rnorm(N, 1, 1)
sample2 <- rnorm(N, 2, 2)

var.test(sample1, sample2)
```

which produces:

```
    F test to compare two variances

data:  sample1 and sample2
F = 0.20433, num df = 99, denom df = 99, p-value = 5.592e-14
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1374845 0.3036882
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
         0.2043341
```

So here we would reject the null hypothesis that the variances are equal.

Comment: In this example the values are generated in such a way that they are identically distributed (within sample). But I am interested in situation, where such an assumption can not  be made (two samples of outcomes of many different random variables rather than samples of outcomes of two random variables).

Comment: If each random variable has a different distribution, it gets delicate to have a common measure of variability.

Comment: For example, heights in Netherlands come from different distribution than heights in Portugal.

Comment: I have modified my question to reduce ambiguity.